# How to clear console in java (Using netbeans)

Tags: java, console

I am using jdj 1.7,netbeans 7 versions. I wrote a program that's working fine. Now i want to clear the console window after many outputs in the console. I tried the below line `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls");` also tried with exec("clear"). But i am getting these errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cls": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:459)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:431)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:328)
at Periodical.main(Book.java:88)
```

Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.(ProcessImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:30)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:452)

What's the problem here. How can i clear the console? Thank you

Comment: this question is operating system dependent. it'd be helpful if you mention the OS are you trying to run the code.

Comment: I am running on Windows 7 professional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep it portable you might want to use a library like [jcurses](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/). That will save you the trouble of having to detect what kind of console/terminal you are on and will give you a lot of other nice features like cursor and color control.